# Can't find source of error in form handling

Tags: jquery

I'm learning to use forms and Ajax with jQuery, but I didn't came far before I got an error message that I can't solve on my own. In the Chrome developer tool, I get a message that there  is no `on` method!? What have I done wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('form.ajax').on('submit', function() {

//console.log('Working!');
alert("test");
return false;   
});

});
```

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using? `on` is from 1.7

Comment: Check that jquery is finding the form with $('form.ajax').length > 0. If its not then your selector is wrong.

Comment: @Jono It wouldn't throw an error even if the selector doesn't find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`on`** was introduced to jQuery v1.7.  Try to upgrade the jQuery library or try using [**`.bind()`**](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

```
$('form.ajax').bind('submit', function() { 
alert("test");
return false;   
});
```

Comment: You solved the problem! I used an old version of jQuery! Thanks!

Comment: @3D-kreativ Glad to help you friend :)